# How do I translate the subject of my password reset email in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, forgot-password

I am new to laravel and I am currently building a multilingual app. I am implementing password reset using laravels shipped methods. After looking at this method in ResetsPasswords trait:

```
 protected function getEmailSubject()
    {
        return isset($this->subject) ? $this->subject : 'Your Password Reset Link';
    }
```

I noticed that I can specify a variable for my subject in the PasswordController like so:

protected $subject = 'Password Reset';

How do I get this value from a language file and assign to the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the trans() helper function in the contructor

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subject = trans('passwords.subject');
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging I found the answer as shown below.

```
protected function getEmailSubject(){
    return Lang::has('passwords.password_reset')
         ? Lang::get('passwords.password_reset')
         : 'Your Password Reset Link.';
}
```

Using method overriding, I overrode the getEmailSubject method in the ResetsPasswords trait and provided the necessary implementation as shown in the body of the email. passwords.password_reset is a key for a text in my language file.